# document.write(xmlDoc..) get text from XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to read a specific line out of an XML document.  It works when 'calling' them directly, but I don't know how to do it with underlying lines.

**Here's the XML file:**

http://rapidimg.org/server/files/50a55cca752a9ciUnOM.png

**Load XML:**

```
// load xml file
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else 
{    
    // IE 5/6
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET", "vragen.xml", false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
```

**Now how do I make it so that in a for loop only answer A is shown? I got the for loop, but how do I continue?**

```
for(i=0; i < totalQuestions; i++)
{
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write((i + 1) + ") " + 
                  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("vragen")[i].childNodes[1].textContent +
                 "<br />");

    document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("vragen")[i].childNodes[2].childNodex[1].textContent);
        //It has to read: vragen/antwoorden/a
}
```

I want it to show the first answer no matter what question I'm in.

Comment: You can't `document.write()` to the XML document and you should not do it in HTML document either. http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite . Try `document.body.innerHTML` instead.

Comment: document.write() works perfectly fine, has always worked. It reads and displays a specific line out of the XML, I just don't know how to read underlying lines like: <vragen><a>test</a></vragen> How do I get to show test?

Comment: I have added a line of code in the Load XML part, if that's what you meant.